# How to give top to bottom animation in Android?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I am able to give bottom to top animation when I go to next activity but now when I pressed back I am using same code for giving animation from top to bottom animation but it always goes to bottom to top so my question is **how to give animation from top to bottom when i pressed back button on android device?**
Please find my code below.

I use it during transitioning from one `Activity` to another using an `Intent`.

```
overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up );
```

and xml is:  slide_in_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

and slide_out_up.xml  is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="-100%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just Change -100 to 100 (remove minus) in slide_out_up.xml

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_anim, R.anim.exit_anim);
}
```

Comment: pls refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306513/exchange-information-after-bluetooth-pairing-with-authentication-only-android

Comment: hi hesam..want to ask another question pls refer above link if u have ever work wid Bluetooth..  after pairing of 2 devices via Bluetooth how to start exchange profile information with authorization request comes in notification..and after accepting it only exchange profile info..i am getting stuck here from 3 days pls help...thanks

Comment: Hi shyam, I saw your link but unfortunately i have no idea. let me search abut it if i got result then I'll tell you. sorry :)

Comment: ok hesam sure... ..u r helping me...so i am v thankful of u.. :)

Answer (score 6):

Worked on my tablet 4.0.3.

**slide_out_up.xml**:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="-100%p" />

</set>
```

**slide_in_up:xml**:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p" />

</set>
```

**style.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="DialogAnimationOutUpInUp">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_up</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_up</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 5):

i just implemented it with two more xml files having like

slide up, 100 to 0 and 0 to -100

slide down -100 to 0 and 0 to 100

it works perfect.

Answer (score 4):

You can override the back button press behavior and set the appropriate animation that you want, like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_anim, R.anim.exit_anim);
}
```

Change the animations at the `overridePendingTransition` so that it fits the ones that you want.

Comment: i do the same as u said but it is giving same animation means bottom to top but i want top to bottom animation when i press back button ,i reversed the overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_up, R.anim.slide_in_up);

Comment: I do the same as you do guy, except that my "slide_out" animation is `android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="100%p"`. It is working just fine around here. Did you add the extra `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` to your `Intent` when you were going to call the next Activity? Does any animation happen?