# Android, exchange information after Bluetooth pairing with authentication only //

Tags: android

i want to exchange some information via Bluetooth with pairing of 2 android devices with authentication only.. i have seen the android chat sample example available in android developer side ..its work well but now i want after Bluetooth pairing of 2 devices , want to exchange some information to each other as when a device send its some information to other devise a authentication pop up would be appear to remote device and if it accepted then only share information to other side...vv thanks in adv....

```
using below code i also want to show authentication before pairing 2 devices via     Bluetooth..but it directly pair without any authentication send to other side
```

code for BluetoothChatService.jave taken from android developer side is below

```
public class BluetoothChatService extends Activity {
    // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChatService";
    private static final boolean D = true;
    // Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
    private static final String NAME = "BluetoothChat";
    // Unique UUID for this application
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
            // ("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
    // Member fields
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private AcceptThread mAcceptThread;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private int mState;
    // Constants that indicate the current connection state
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0; // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1; // now listening for incoming
    // connections
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing
    // connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3; // now connected to a remote
    // device

    /**
     * Constructor. Prepares a new BluetoothChat session.
     * 
     * @param context
     *            The UI Activity Context
     * @param handler
     *            A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
     */
    public BluetoothChatService(Context context, Handler handler) {
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mState = STATE_NONE;
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    /**
     * Set the current state of the chat connection
     * 
     * @param state
     *            An integer defining the current connection state
     */
    private synchronized void setState(int state) {
        if (D) {
            Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
        }
        mState = state;

        // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
        mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1)
                .sendToTarget();
    }

    /**
     * Return the current connection state.
     */
    public synchronized int getState() {
        return mState;
    }

    /**
     * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
     * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume()
     */
    public synchronized void start() {
        if (D) {
            Log.d(TAG, "start");
        }

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
        if (mAcceptThread == null) {
            mAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            mAcceptThread.start();
        }
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
     * 
     * @param device
     *            The BluetoothDevice to connect
     */
    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D) {
            Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);
        }

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
            if (mConnectThread != null) {
                mConnectThread.cancel();
                mConnectThread = null;
            }
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to connect with the given device
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
        mConnectThread.start();
        setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
     * 
     * @param socket
     *            The BluetoothSocket on which the connection was made
     * @param device
     *            The BluetoothDevice that has been connected
     */
    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket,
            BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D) {
            Log.d(TAG, "connected");
        }

        // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one
        // device
        if (mAcceptThread != null) {
            mAcceptThread.cancel();
            mAcceptThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(BluetoothChat.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    }

    /**
     * Stop all threads
     */
    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (D) {
            Log.d(TAG, "stop");
        }
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }
        if (mAcceptThread != null) {
            mAcceptThread.cancel();
            mAcceptThread = null;
        }
        setState(STATE_NONE);
    }

    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     * 
     * @param out
     *            The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                return;
            }
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionFailed() {
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);

        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(BluetoothChat.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionLost() {
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);
        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(BluetoothChat.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

/**
 * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
 * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted (or
 * until cancelled).
 */
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    // The local server socket
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

        // Create a new listening server socket
        try {

            tmp = mAdapter
                    .listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
//                if(!tmp.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(null)){

//              
  //          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "listen() failed", e);
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (D) {
            Log.d(TAG, "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
        }
        setName("AcceptThread");
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
        while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {


                try {
                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                    switch (mState) {
                    case STATE_LISTEN:
                    case STATE_CONNECTING:
                        // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                        connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                        break;
                    case STATE_NONE:
                    case STATE_CONNECTED:
                        // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate
                        // new socket.
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG,"Could not close unwanted socket",
                                            e);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (D) {
            Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread");
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        if (D) {
            Log.d(TAG, "cancel " + this);
        }
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of server failed", e);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection with a
 * device. It runs straight through; the connection either succeeds or
 * fails.
 */
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;


        try {
            try {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
        setName("ConnectThread");

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            connectionFailed();
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e(TAG,"unable to close() socket during connection failure",
                                e2);
            }
            // Start the service over to restart listening mode
            BluetoothChatService.this.start();
            return;
        }

        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device. It handles all
 * incoming and outgoing transmissions.
 */
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

    private final InputStream mmInStream;

    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity

                // XXX !!!
                String buffer2 = new String(buffer);
                buffer2= buffer2.substring(0, buffer2.length()-3)+"\n";

                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, bytes,
                        -1, buffer2.getBytes()).sendToTarget();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write to the connected OutStream.
     * 
     * @param buffer
     *            The bytes to write
     */
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);

            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity

            // XXX !!!
            String buffer2 = new String(buffer);
            buffer2= buffer2.substring(0, buffer2.length()-2);
            mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1,
                    buffer2.getBytes()).sendToTarget();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```