# Android view slide in from top to bottom

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-xml, viewanimator

I want my view to perform a slide in top - slide out bottom.

What I have so far is

**slide_in_top.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
               android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="-100%p"
               android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

**slide_out_bottom.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
               android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="100%p"
               android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

My new view should come from top and previous view should hide from to bottom.
But this is not working as expected. I cant find a proper documentation even how to work with `<translate>` tag.
I am using `ViewAnimator` to animate my views. 
A help would be great. Thanks.
And also I need a good explanation how it works like`<translate android:fromYDelta android:fromXDelta>` how these works with 'in animation' and 'animation out'

Comment: You can get all from here http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/res/anim/?r=3 And see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754043/how-to-give-top-to-bottom-animation-android