# Best strategy to show a image on the screen that moves from up to down?

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, imageview, surfaceview

I want to show a png image that must be stretched to 100% of the width of the screen and 5% of the height of the screen, and the image must move from the top of the screen to the bottom of the screen in 5 seconds.

Wich is the best strategy to achieve this?

I know that you can specify the position of a ImageView in a FrameLayout, but i'm sure that there is a better way to achieve this, but i dont know how.

The code must be compatible with API level 9. (Android 2.3)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get all from here 
http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/res/anim/?r=3

And see this post how to give top to bottom animation android
[How to give top to bottom animation in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754043/how-to-give-top-to-bottom-animation-android)